# Open and sync shared OneDrive document from Windows Explorer

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, sync, onedrive

I am currently using Windows 8.1 and Office 365. I have a few documents that I share with colleagues, and we are trying to take advantage of OneDrive's built-in simultaneous editing tools. The problem is that I can't get simultaneous editing to work when I open a document from Windows Explorer. Here are the steps to reproduce what I'm seeing:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Select "OneDrive" from the left side pane
3. Open a document that is labeled as shared
4. Expected: Document opens with "syncing save" icon [image: Word Syncing Save icon]. Actual behavior: I get the regular save icon. If I save the file while someone else is editing, I get a duplicate copy created with my computer name appended to the filename.

When I open the document via the OneDrive website at https://onedrive.live.com, I can select "Open in Word" and I get the save icon as I'm expecting. Is there a way to get the syncing behavior to function when opening files directly? Or do I have to remember to open through the website every time?

Comment: It appears that, at least in 2012, it was not possible in the SkyDrive desktop application: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsharing/im-confused-about-how-to-collaborating-on-word/b4304695-1e81-48f4-9264-58882cf57064